# How can my main Python application run a script in a subpackage which reads a file within the subpackage

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to allow foo.py to load file.txt using relative import but I'm hitting a FileNotFoundError.

```
 -- main.py
|
 --- submodule
       |
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- foo.py
       |-- file.txt
```

main.py

```py
import os
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('.foo', package='submodule')
```

foo.py

```py
file = open("file.txt","a")
```

I expected foo.py to be able to read since file.txt is in the same sub-directory. I know I can put the absolute path in foo.py but I want to know how to use the relative path in foo.py to load file.txt.

Comment: Technical answer already provided by simkus. Now since I noticed you open your file for appending,  I'd like to point out that files that live in your source tree should be considered as read-only (only developpers should edit them, and then commit their changes to the version control system). If your code needs to _write_ to files, it should use a directory that's outside the source tree (user's home, some system or settings defined destination, etc). Or, if it's for logging purposes, use the `logging` package...

Comment: Hi @brunodesthuilliers, thanks for the information. Fortunately, the code for opening the file is just a placeholder, I'm actually doing something else there but was just having trouble referencing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating `current_dir` variable in your `foo.py` file which then you can use to get the `file.txt`

Example of how `foo.py` should look:

```py
import os

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def read_file():
    x = os.path.join(current_dir, 'file.txt')
    with open(x, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
```

How it works, is that the first part `os.path.realpath(__file__)` gets you the `foo.py` file location in your project and the second part `os.path.dirname` will get the directory name where this `foo.py` exists. So this way you build your file path to `file.txt` in `foo.py` so that `main.py` could execute `foo.py` in order to get the content of a `file.txt`

And `main.py`:

```py
from submodule import foo

print(foo.read_file())
```

Comment: Would have been a better answer with a mention of the "current working directory" concept (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the comment on this :)